# Converting CSS Lch to RGB

Tags: javascript, css, colors, color-space, lab-color-space

I wanted to convert a CSS Lch color string like:

```css
--my-color: lch(20% 8.5 220.0);
```

To an RGB hex code. I tried using tools like [chroma's Lch parser](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#color-lch), but all of them seem to use absolute values for the first ordinate (the 20% in my case).

Is there some standard way to convert that 20% into the lightness values used by most Lch conversion tools?

Comment: first https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#lch-to-lab then https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#lab-to-rgb

Comment: You can just scale, if you have different ranges. BTW, it is not a good question writing "used by most ...". We have no idea on which tools you consider (and your field). You should always specify range and colour space (in question, but remember to write it also in the code, or next time it will take huge amount of time to find out errors and your definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The w3c is working on a draft and there is [example code in javascript](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#color-conversion-code) attached (it's a bit too long to post here and you'll need higher math to do that (at least `sin` and the power of `2.4`).

Answer (score 3):

A JS-native CanvasRenderingContext2D instance can read any CSS-formatted color (as a string) and write it in a RGBA buffer (0 to 255) for you :

```
const myCssColor  = "lch(20% 8.5 220.0)";

function cssColor_to_rgba255Color(string) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvas.height = 1;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", {willReadFrequently: true});
    ctx.fillStyle = string;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
}

const rgba = cssColor_to_rgba255Color(myCssColor);

console.log( rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3] );
// 33 51 56 255
```

This function may have poor performance but can be greatly optimized by always recycling (using clearRect) the same "ctx" object.

Comment: At least we're sure that it uses the browser's implementation of (OK)LCH and it doesn't require doing any math

Answer (score 1):

I can give you this function that I wrote for myself from LCH to HEX, or RGB if you want. I wrote it in PHP, so it's easy to adapt to any other language

```
function lch2hex($l, $c, $h) {
  $a=round($c*cos(deg2rad($h)));
  $b=round($c*sin(deg2rad($h)));
  unset($c,$h);
  
  // Reference white values for D65 Light Europe Observer
  // $xw = 0.95047;
  // $yw = 1.00000;
  // $zw = 1.08883;
  
  // Reference white values for CIE 1964 10° Standard Observer
  $xw = 0.948110;
  $yw = 1.00000;
  $zw = 1.07304;
  
  // Compute intermediate values
  $fy = ($l + 16) / 116;
  $fx = $fy + ($a / 500);
  $fz = $fy - ($b / 200);
  
  // Compute XYZ values
  $x = round($xw * (($fx ** 3 > 0.008856) ? $fx ** 3 : (($fx - 16 / 116) / 7.787)),5);
  $y = round($yw * (($fy ** 3 > 0.008856) ? $fy ** 3 : (($fy - 16 / 116) / 7.787)),5);
  $z = round($zw * (($fz ** 3 > 0.008856) ? $fz ** 3 : (($fz - 16 / 116) / 7.787)),5);
  unset($l,$a,$b,$xw,$yw,$zw,$fy,$fx,$fz);
  
  $r = $x * 3.2406 - $y * 1.5372 - $z * 0.4986;
  $g = -$x * 0.9689 + $y * 1.8758 + $z * 0.0415;
  $b = $x * 0.0557 - $y * 0.2040 + $z * 1.0570;
  unset($x,$y,$z);

  $r = $r > 0.0031308 ? 1.055 * pow($r, 1 / 2.4) - 0.055 : 12.92 * $r;
  $g = $g > 0.0031308 ? 1.055 * pow($g, 1 / 2.4) - 0.055 : 12.92 * $g;
  $b = $b > 0.0031308 ? 1.055 * pow($b, 1 / 2.4) - 0.055 : 12.92 * $b;

  $r = round(max(min($r, 1), 0) * 255);
  $g = round(max(min($g, 1), 0) * 255);
  $b = round(max(min($b, 1), 0) * 255);
  
  return '#' . sprintf('%02X%02X%02X', $r, $g, $b);
  }
```